# 3d projection help?

Tags: 3d, projection

I've been wanting to know how to do 3d projections.[image]

Can someone explain how i can use this to find the position for x and y on the 2d plane that is 600 * 600 pixels.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a position for x and y on a screen?" Are you asking how to get a point on the surface of 3D geometry, or how to project 3D geometry into 2D for rendering?

Comment: In other words, what would be the output you're looking for? A 3D coordinate? A color? Distance from the camera surface (depth)?

Comment: I meant the 2d plane that the 3d points are going to be projected onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to compute the position that an arbitrary 3D vertex (x,y,z,1) has on the view plane after the projection: You can use the given parameters to compute a projection matrix:

[image: Matrix]

where `f = cotangent(fovy * 0.5)`

This is also the matrix that will be set by a call to [gluPerspective](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml). Then, you can multiply this matrix with your vertex to obtain the projected vertex position.

Comment: In the vertex matrix would it contain [x,y,z,1] or just [x,y,z]?

Comment: Also what is fovy? Is it the distance to the 2d plane?

Comment: @Funshine For some [mathematical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) reasons, the vertex must be a 4D point. You can just add "1" as the last component of the 3D point that you already have. And `fovy` is the "Field Of View", in Y-direction. Basically "the (vertical) opening angle" of the view frustum.

Comment: How do i find the value of fovy?

Comment: Would it be (tan^-1(D/(W/2)))*2 where D is the distance to the 2d plane and W is the width?

Comment: According to http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html it should be `2*atan(H*0.5/D)`, which is similar to what you suggested, but I did not verify this...

Comment: Is this image correct about after multiplying the matrices together? Also notice the x,y, and z that i have that correspond to a row in the matrix are they in the correct spot? http://postimg.org/image/4ua7x5039/

Comment: I think it should be `.../ (n-f)` for the z-component, shouldn't it? (Again, I did not go through all this with pen+paper for many years now, usually, OpenGL does things like this for you ;-))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27477/discussion-between-funshine-and-marco13).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to use a bunch of matrices. With the traditional OpenGL pipeline, you'd have to mutiply these matrices:

```
finalMatrix = modelMatrix
  *
  viewMatrix
  * 
  projectionMatrix
  * 
  viewport.windowMatrix;
```

To find the position of the vertex on your viewport, just multiply the vertex by the matrix:

```
onViewportVertex = in3dVertex * finalMatrix;
```

Of course, this implies that no shader modifies the vertex or the pixel.